# Excel VBA .find issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am a new member of this forum but have done some searching for this particular problem. I haven't found anything yet.

I have a need for a `VBA` script which searches for a value located in a cell `I7` in the first workbook `wb1`, and reference that entry to a column `A:A` in a sheet called "Codes" in another workbook `wb2`, if it finds the value in Cell `I7` in Column `A:A` it will put the text "Value Found" into Cell `I7`. If it doesn't find that value in the column range, it will copy and paste the old value from the old sheet to the new one as it is.

Excel seems to be executing the code, but the problem I'm getting is that if the value is not located in the columns that are referenced, the code doesn't seem to pick it up, therefore the code just puts the "Value Found" into the target cell no matter if the value is found in the referenced columns, am I missing something here?

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook, 
Dim Sh1 as Worksheet
Dim WBS as Range

Set Sh1 = wb1.Sheets("Codes").Range("A:A")
Set WBS = Sh1.Columns(1).Find(What:=wb2.Sheets("Summary").Range("I7:I7").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,     MatchCase:=False)
If WBS Is Nothing Then
wb1.Sheets("Summary").Range("I7:I7").Copy
wb2.Sheets("Summary").Range("I7:I7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Else
wb2.Sheets("Summary").Range("I7:I7").Value = "'Value Found"
End If
```

Comment: not exactly a forum - a sort of forum on steroids!

Comment: I don't understand why your posted code does not --> errors.  You never set wb1 to anything; you are setting a Worksheet object (SH1) to a range (should --> Type Mismatch).  Also, note that Range("I7") is sufficient; no need for Range("I7:I7").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ron has commented your declarations and instantiations need some amendments. Where do you `Set` wb1 and wb2 in your code?

This simplified version works fine:

```
Sub simplified()

Dim rn1 As Range
Dim WBS As Range

Set rn1 = Range("A:A")
Set WBS = rn1.Find( _
        What:=Range("I7").Value, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)

If WBS Is Nothing Then
    Range("I7").Copy
    Range("J7").PasteSpecial Paste:= Excel.xlValues
Else
    Range("J7").Value = "'Value Found"
End If

End Sub
```

Results are simplified to just one sheet in a single workbook:

[image]